# Haskell syntax error: unexpected `;' possibly due to bad layout

Tags: haskell, syntax, ghci, hugs

For quite some time now I have been receiving this error on the fourth line :
    Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `;', possibly due to bad layout)
In the following code snippet:

```
import Data.Maybe    

leesIngrediënten:: Int->[[Char]]->[Int]->[Maybe [Char]]->[[Char]]->([Int], [Maybe [Char]], [[Char]])
leesIngrediënten 0 _ hoevs eenhs naams = (hoevs, eenhs, naams)
leesIngrediënten n (line:lines) hoevs eenhs naams =
                 let 
                     (hoev, eenh, naam) = leesLijn line
                     in  
                       leesIngrediënten (n-1) lines (hoev:hoevs) (eenh:eenhs) (naam:naams)
```

After searching on the internet I found what the error meant, but the point is I don't see my mistake. (probably because I wrote the code)

The weird thing is, Hugs is the one complaining where GHCi has nothing to complain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, Hugs is old and no longer supported. It could just be a bug. However, I'm surprised that you indent `in` further than `let` and GHC still accepts it...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid That is needed otherwise a single line `let x=5 in ...` would be rejected. Note that the position of `let` is also irrelevant (as long as it does not close an open block by being too on the left), it's the position of the first non-char after `let` that matters. The `in` will close the `let` block anywhere that might be (if on the right, it causes a parse error, and the standard IIRC states that in such case you close a block and retry parsing -- yes, it's tricky...)

Comment: Uewwww, this signature is terrible! Use some aliases at least.

Comment: Pretty new to Haskell, didn't know what aliases were. But thanks for mentioning it, will use it from now on!

Answer (score 5):

According to https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/users_guide/haskell98.html, Hugs doesn't support Unicode identifiers. This probably leads to the syntax error.

Comment: Ow. I thought my edit was immaterial... Sorry about this

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like the the Problem comes with the Unicode identifiers. When I run your code i get

`3:12: lexical error (UTF-8 decoding error)`

But it is important if the file is an already compiled one or not. If its an `exe`, dont use `runhaskell`. That could cause the Problem too. And a little hint for the future, your code is much easier to read, when you use more spaces between words and punctuation marks.